# Positioning button

Tags: html, css

I was centering the elements of my page with:

```
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

but when I try to do this with one div that has two buttons they stay in the left corner, why? and how I place them in the center.

Comment: Just use text-align: center; on the parent div. It will align both buttons on center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**
If both the buttons are inside the `div` container you also need to specify the width of the div container, because by default div covers the complete width.

```css
div{
  max-width:10rem;
  margin :0px auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>Button1</button>
  <button>Button2</button>
</div>
```

**Option 2**
You can also flex the div container to center the buttons

```css
div{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <button>Button1</button>
  <button>Button2</button>
</div>
```

**Option 3**
You can also use the simple text align center property on the div container so it will center the buttons

```css
div{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>Button1</button>
  <button>Button2</button>
</div>
```

because buttons are inline elements.

Answer (score -1):

The div css:

```
text-align: center
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about the context but you can use this centering pattern (both horizontal and vertical) with Flexbox as well:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Positioning is very easy with flexbox. Please try following properties on your div

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

Justify content will place content centrally along horizontal axis and align items will place content centrally along vertical axis (for flex direction row which is default)